# Removing Elements in A from B

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists, let's say:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

I would like to remove 1, 2 and 3 from list b, but not all occurrences. The resulting list should have:

```
b = [1,2,3]
```

I currently have:

```
for element in a:
    try:
        b.remove(element)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

However, this has poor performance when a and b get very large. Is there a more efficient way of getting the same results?

**EDIT**

To clarify 'not all occurrences', I mean I do not wish to remove both '1's from b, as there was only one '1' in a.

Comment: "But not all occurrences" - could you explain a bit more? Are you trying to delete just the first occurrence? or all but the last occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

# Build up the count of occurrences in b
d = defaultdict(int)
for bb in b:
    d[bb] += 1

# Remove one for each occurrence in a
for aa in a:
    d[aa] -= 1

# Create a list for all elements that still have a count of one or more
result = []
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if v > 0:
        result += [k] * v
```

Or, if you are willing to be slightly more obscure:

```
from operator import iadd

result = reduce(iadd, [[k] * v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v > 0], [])
```

defaultdict generates a count of the occurrences of each key. Once it has been built up from `b`, it is decremented for each occurrence of a key in `a`. Then we print out the elements that are still left over, allowing them to occur multiple times.

defaultdict works with python 2.6 and up. If you are using a later python (2.7 and up, I believe), you can look into [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

---

Later: you can also generalize this and create subtractions of counter-style defaultdicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import iadd

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

def build_dd(lst):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for item in lst:
        d[item] += 1
    return d

def subtract_dd(left, right):
    return {k: left[k] - v for k, v in right.iteritems()}

db = build_dd(b)
da = build_dd(a)
result = reduce(iadd,
                [[k] * v for k, v in subtract_dd(db, da).iteritems() if v > 0],
                [])

print result
```

But the `reduce` expression is pretty obscure now.

---

Later still: in python 2.7 and later, using `collections.Counter`, it looks like this:

```
from collections import Counter

base = [1, 2, 3]
missing = [4, 5, 6]
extra = [7, 8, 9]
a = base + missing
b = base * 4 + extra

result = Counter(b) - Counter(a)
print result
assert result == dict([(k, 3) for k in base] + [(k, 1) for k in extra])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
set_a = set(a)
new_b = []
for x in b:
  if x in set_a:
    set_a.remove(x)
  else:
    new_b.append(x)
```

Unlike the other set solutions, this maintains order in `b` (if you care about that).

Comment: Thanks. This works as well, although I am not so concerned about order.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to always avoid list.remove() (you are right, it would hurt the performance really badly). Also, it is much faster (O(1)) to look up elements in a dictionary or a set than in a list; so create a set out of your list1 (and if order doesn't matter, out of your list2).

Something like this:

```
sa = set(a)
new_b = [x for x in b if not x in sa]
# here you created a 3d list but I bet it's OK.
```

However I have no idea what is your actual algo for choosing elements for removal. Please elaborate on "but not all occurrences".

Comment: You're on the right track, but if a contains [1,2,3] and b contains [1,1,2,2,3,3], new_b will contain []. If there is one '1' in a, I only wish for one '1' in b to be removed.

Comment: Re: 'Please elaborate on "but not all occurrences".' I took OP to mean that if there are n-occurrences of x in the leftbut only m-occurrences of x in the right, then x-y will have `max(n-m, 0)`occurrences of x in `left - right`.